# Invoke Method of Subclass with Matching Regex

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to call a method, `convert()`, based upon the return value matching the class' `regex()` method, both of which are defined in the below base class:

```
public abstract class BaseClass {
    public abstract BaseClass convert(String value);
    public abstract String regex();
}
```

I also have several subclasses that have implementations of those methods. I want to be able to do something like the below method (which will reside in `BaseClass`):

```
public static BaseClass parseNew (String value) {

    // I use a switch statement to convey the idea of what I want to
    // do, not for functionallity. Any non-constant cases raise
    // compiler errors.
    switch (value) {
        case new Subclass1().regex():
            return new Subclass1().convert(value);
        case new Subclass1().regex():
            return new Subclass1().convert(value);
        // Repeat for all known and possibly unknown subclasses
    }
}
```

I was thinking about using reflection, but I am very afluent in it. How would I get this functionality using reflection or some other concept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with this design is that it breaks abstraction (base aware of sub classes), making it a terrible idea.

A little about abstraction:

> Abstraction is a process of hiding the implementation details from the user. Оnly the functionality will be provided to the user.

Instead you could make a different class which will contain this logic, and will act as a sort of *factory*.

Basically, you provide a *base* which exposes operations. This *base* is at the top of your inheritance tree. From it you provide implementations. The base in not aware of those implementations, they are not connected, they are specific. So the *base* class should know that *sub* exists, this just causes the code to be coupled and makes it non-modular and hard to maintain.

This mostly relates to creating a *clean code*.

So a quick look into factories... We want an object which will receive a `value` and parse it into an instance of `BaseClass`.

```
public class Parser {

    private final Collection<BaseClass> implementations;

    public Parser(Collection<BaseClass> implementations) {
         this.implementations = implementations;
    }

    public BaseClass parseNew(String value) {
         for (BaseClass implementation : implementations) {
             if (implementation.regex().equals(value)) {
                 return implementation.convert(value);
             }
         }

         throw new IllegalArgumentException("unsupported value");
    }
}
```

The `Parser` class above is a *factory* which contains a collection of known `BaseClass` implementations. Using those, it may determine which implementation is wanted.

This is a pretty dynamic implementation. You would want to create an instance of this factory once, with the known implementations, and use it wherever.

**General Design Note**

There is also something weird about the the fact that `BaseClass.convert` returns `BaseClass`. I would expect it to return something else. `BaseClass` seems like a *converter*, and `convert` should return a *value*.

But that's just a general note.

**Some reading resources:**

- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/design-patterns-set-2-factory-method/
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm
- https://javatutorial.net/java-abstraction-example
- http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/relation-between-a-super-class-and-a-class